# Vitest / Testing Library React / @media test for toBeVisible

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

I am using quite standard setup for React application with Vite + Vitest. I have created project with `npm create vite@latest` for React + Typescript. After I have added Vitest as it is mentioned here in example from [Vitest GitHub](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/blob/main/examples/react-testing-lib/package.json).

I want to test component for appearing and disappearing text tag depending on CSS @media.

```
import { describe, test, expect, vi, afterEach } from "vitest";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

afterEach(() => {
  vi.unstubAllGlobals();
});

describe("App", () => {
  test("Test on mobile", () => {
    vi.stubGlobal("innerWidth", 414);
    render(<App />);
    expect(window.innerWidth).toEqual(414);
    expect(screen.getByTestId("always")).toBeVisible();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("desktop-only")).not.toBeVisible();
  });
  test("Test on desktop", () => {
    vi.stubGlobal("innerWidth", 1200);
    render(<App />);
    expect(window.innerWidth).toEqual(1200);
    expect(screen.getByTestId("always")).toBeVisible();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("desktop-only")).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

TEXT tag is must be visible since after 768px it gets `display: inline;` instead of `display: block;`. But test is failing.
Second part is passing and `window.innerWidth` inside `<Header />` also returns 1024.
I also tried to set window viewport as it is advised [here](https://www.js-howto.com/test-responsive-design-using-jest-and-react-testing-library/). But with same result.
What I am doing wrong?

Here is [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vitest-react-responsive-test-kjvs9n) where I have recreated the case. To run test execute `yarn test` in terminal, please.